# Very simple increment function in objects list

Tags: javascript, oop

I’m trying to replicate a very simple function that I can get to work with arrays but not with objects. I just want to be able to run a function that logs the next object number as with the numbers array.

Take this working array as an example:

```
var numbers = [4,2,6],
    count = 0;

incrementArr();

function incrementArr() {
  if (count < numbers.length) { // if not last array element
    console.log(numbers[count]);
    count++;
  } else {
    console.log(numbers[0]);
    count = 1;
  }
}
```

Whenever you run the incrementArr function, it’ll just log the next number and then return to the start if the current state (count) is at the end.

However, I cannot replicate the same principle with this object list:

```
var objs = {
  first: { // doesn't have to have 'first'
    "number": 4
  },
  second: { // doesn't have to have 'second'
    "number": 2
  },
  third: { // doesn't have to have 'third'
    "number": 6
  }
},
  count = 0;

incrementObj();

function incrementObj() {
  if (count < Object.keys(objs).length) { // if not last obj element
    //objs["first"].number
    console.log(objs[count].number);
    count++;
  } else {
    console.log(objs["first"].number); // what if no "first" in objects?
    count++;
  }
}
```

1. How could the `incrementObj` function work the same way that the previous `incrementArr` function works?

It seems that I can’t pick the specific object instance (e.g. numbers[1] from the array would pick the 2nd number, but only objs[“second”].number would pick the 2nd object, which isn’t iterable if you know what I mean). How could I get a workaround for typical circumstances like this?

So essentially, what’s the difference between this:

```
first: { // doesn't have to have 'first'
  "number": 4
}
```

and:

```
{ // doesn't have to have 'first'
  "number": 4
}
```

2. Why have the "first" etc? (called the key?)

Is there generally a better way of going about object lists (it's difficult to explain)? Thanks for any advice here.

Comment: You should look into generators and iterators.

Comment: Regarding 1: You could make an array with your keys: `keys = ['first','second','third']` and when indexing for your `console.log` you would do `objs[keys[count]]`. Regarding 2: if you want a list of objects, simply make that: `[{number: 4},{number: 2},{number: 6}]`. If you don't need the keys first, second etc., then don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over the object and get the keys and store an index. The returned function get the value and increment and adjusts the index.

```js
function increment(object) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object),
        index = 0;

    return function() {
        var value = object[keys[index]].number; 
        index++;
        index %= keys.length;
        return value;
    };
}

var objs = { first: { number: 4 }, second: { number: 2 }, third: { number: 6 } },
    incrementObj = increment(objs);

console.log(incrementObj());
console.log(incrementObj());
console.log(incrementObj());
console.log(incrementObj());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it access keys through the array generated from keys, objects are unordered list that means you will have to at least order the keys and access them in the array order.

```
const keysArr = Object.keys(objs);
function incrementObj() {

  if (count < keysArr.length) { // if not last obj element
    //
    console.log(objs[keysArr[count]].number);
    count++;
  } else {
    console.log(objs["first"].number); // what if no "first" in objects?
    count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose using [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/WNvPwVZ?editors=1012)

If your object have specific shapes, then you use this as a lens to find the `number` property you want. I'm not sure how you want to use the iterator and have return both the key and the value as separate properties, but you can as well return `{ [keys[nextIndex]]: values[nextIndex] }` or find other shape (*the world is your oyster*).

Provided you go this length, why not try use [RxJs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) to make your object an observable?

```js
var objs = {
  first: { // doesn't have to have 'first'
    "number": 4
  },
  second: { // doesn't have to have 'second'
    "number": 2
  },
  third: { // doesn't have to have 'third'
    "number": 6
  }
}

function propertyIterator(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  const values = Object.values(obj)
  const length = keys.length
  let nextIndex = 0

  return {
    next: function() {
      const value = {
        key: keys[nextIndex],
        value: values[nextIndex]
      }
      let done = false

      if (nextIndex >= length) {
        done = true
      }
      nextIndex += 1
      return { current: value, done: done}
    }
  }
}

const incrementObj = propertyIterator(objs)

let result = incrementObj.next()
console.log(result.current.key, result.current.value.number || NaN)
result = incrementObj.next()
console.log(result.current.key, result.current.value.number || NaN)
result = incrementObj.next()
console.log(result.current.key, result.current.value.number || NaN)
```

using [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/poJGbyK):

```js
const objs = {
  first: { // doesn't have to have 'first'
    "number": 4
  },
  second: { // doesn't have to have 'second'
    "number": 2
  },
  third: { // doesn't have to have 'third'
    "number": 6
  }
}

const inc = defaultValue => prop => function* (obj) {
  for(let key in obj) {
    yield obj[key][prop] || defaultValue
  }
}

const getNumber = inc(NaN)('number')
const it = getNumber(objs)

let result = it.next()
while (!result.done) {
 console.log(result.value)
 result = it.next()
}
```